# Directory.GetFiles crashes Visual Studio

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012, crash, .net-4.5

In my application I need to let the user specify a path. This path is then being examined recursively for any existing measurement data files with a `.txt` extension. This generally works quite well, but during my tests I ran into a problem: when I select a "sensitive" directory like `C:\WINDOWS`, Visual Studio completely crashes. This is my code:

```
        try
        {
            var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(DataDirPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return;
        }
```

When I run this and select the Windows dir as `DataDirPath`, the following happens:

1. As expected, the exception is catched and the MessageBox shows that access to the path c:\Windows\AppCompat\Programs has been denied
2. After clicking ok in the MessageBox, Visual Studio crashes. It shows a windows stating the VS doesn't function properly anymore and it offers restarting VS or debugging it (VS, not my program).

How can that happen? How can I avoid this? This happens in debug as well as in release build. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Visual Studio crash isn't happening in this code, so where do you use the fileNames variable or expect something to have been set which isn't? Show us the calling code.